# При присвоении переменной VBA меняется тип данных

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic, vbscript

Присваиваю ячейку из переменной "cell" переменной "prevCellValue"
В переменной "prevCellValue" остается значение, но не ссылка на ячейку как было в "cell"

Как при присвоении оставить типы переменных одинаковыми?

[image: VBA CODE]

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было использовать `set` для полного копирования

```
set a = b
```

Comment: Оператор `Set` выполняет копирование ссылки на объект, а не "полное копирование". Вы чуток ошиблись с формулировкой, но в целом правы - здесь нужен именно "Set". Автор вопроса налетел на пару не очень очевидных моментов: 1) когда не указан явно оператор Let/Set, а тип переменной слева - `Variant`, VBA предпочитает использовать Let; 2) у объекта `Range` есть дефолтное свойство `Value`, которое как раз и позволяет неявное использование `Let` (что VBA и делает "под капотом": `Let prevCellValue = cell.Value`). Указав же явно `Set`, получим то, что хотел автор.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас `prevCellValue` сначала как значение (сравнивается с константой):

```
If  prevCellValue <> -111111 Then
```

потом в переменную пытаетесь передать объект:

```
prevCellValue = cell
```

Но объект в переменую передается с помощью оператора  `Set`. А так как переменная до этого содержала значение и нет оператора присваивания, редактор понимает, что в переменную из `cell` нужно передать значение.

Чтобы подобные ошибки не возникали:

1) сверху модуля, над всеми объявлениями глобальных переменных и процедурами вписать оператор `Option Explicit`;

2) все переменные должны быть объявлены;

3) объявлять переменные очень желательно с указанием их типов:

```
Dim SheetOrder As Worksheet
Dim rRangeTime As Range
Dim i As Long
```

4) перед отладкой (да и в процессе написания кода) компилировать программу (`Debug - Compile VBAProject`).

Эти нехитрые приемы помогут избежать многих ошибок и сэкономят время при  отладке кода.

Попутные замечания.

Переменным желательно давать понятные имена. По имени 'prevCellValue' можно понять, что переменая предназначена для хранения значения ячейки  (`Value`), но никак не самой ячейки как объекта ...

После использования переменных с присвоенными объектами принудительно освобождать память:

```
Set prevCellValue = Nothing
```